# System of $2$ nonlinear DEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

Please tell me if I'm on the right track for solving the following system:

$$\frac{d{U}}{dt}=a - b U -\frac{\beta U V}{U+V}
\\
\frac{d{V}}{dt}=\frac{\beta U V}{U+V}-(b+c+d)V
$$

**Steps:**

$1.$ I added the two equations to get $$\frac{d{U}}{dt}+b U=a-(b+c+d)V-\frac{d{V}}{dt}$$

$2.$ Then I solved for $U$.

$3.$ Then I solved the equation in Step $1$ for $V$.

$4.$ Now I am plugging in the expression for $U$ into the equation for $V$ (because it looks easier than plugging in the other way around).

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you allowed to use numerical methods?

Comment: I am trying to find an analytical solution only - numerical methods are not valid in this context.

Comment: Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Your system of DEs is nonlinear. Most of nonlinear DEs do not have analytical/exact solutions and one has to seek numerical solutions. This system of yours is in this category and there no way to obtain analytical solution.